Streaming large file upload to Google Drive without storing it locally
I have an Ubuntu server with limited available storage space (approximately 3GB). I need to download a large file (around 100GB) and save it directly to my Google Drive account, without storing it on my server. I'm looking for a way to achieve this without running out of storage space on my server.
What options are available to stream the download directly to Google Drive?
Thank you in advance for any guidance or suggestions.

As far as I am aware Google drive does not allow this kind of third party file transfer. Suggest you check with them.

Have you looked at google-drive-ocamlfuse. That lets you mount a gdrive area on a local directory (like NFS). If you do that, you could download your file directly into that area.

I discovered that this is possible with curl and rclone:
curl -L <download url> | rclone -P -v rcat <drive name>:<path to file>

I also found that rclone has a built-in feature called rclone copyurl which achieves the same result.
